# listBox not displaying desired results from a dataSource with C#

Tags: c#, listbox, datasource

My code below is displaying this when run:

[image]

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\us-500.csv";
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);
var lines = new List<string[]>();
int Row = 0;
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string[] Line = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
    lines.Add(Line);
    Row++;
}

var data = lines.ToArray();

bindingSource1.DataSource = data;
listBox1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

How do i get it to show me each rows fields like below?

[image]

Comment: You declare a list of "arrays", but your desired output is not an array, but a single string in a list.  Maybe you just want `var data = lines[0].ToArray();`

Comment: That would be great if that was the only line I needed, but I want move through the CSV file with a bindingNavagator. But thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays aren't great to work with when using DataSources.  Avoid converting your list into an array since it isn't necessary.

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = lines;
bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bindingSource1;
```

Then try using the PositionChanged event of the BindingSource to set the DataSource for the ListBox:

```
void bindingSource1_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var items = bindingSource1.DataSource as List<string[]>;
  if (items != null && bindingSource1.Position >= 0 && 
                       bindingSource1.Position < items.Count ) {
    listBox1.DataSource = items[bindingSource1.Position];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, I think this will do it.

1. Read each line
2. Split each line into multiple fields
3. Add each field to DataSource
4. Bind to DataSource

.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace PopulateListBoxFromCSV_46815162
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ListBox lstbx = new ListBox();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            initializeListBox();
            //fillTheListBox(@"C:\temp\myfile.csv");
            fillTheListBox(@"C:\temp\myfile.csv", true);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Lets say you want to show field value only
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath"></param>
        private void fillTheListBox(string filePath)
        {

            List<string> results = new List<string>();
            string currentLine = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)//for as long as there is something to read
                {
                    foreach (string item in currentLine.Split(','))//split the current line into multiple "fields"
                    {
                        results.Add(item);//add each individual field to the dataSource to create your 1FieldPerLine visual
                    }
                }
            }
            lstbx.DataSource = results;//bind your datasource
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Lets say you wanted to show "Header" : "FieldValue"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath"></param>
        /// <param name="ShowHeader"></param>
        private void fillTheListBox(string filePath, bool ShowHeader)
        {
            List<string> headerLine = new List<string>();
            List<string> results = new List<string>();
            int whichLineAmIon = 0;
            string currentLine = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)//for as long as there is something to read
                {
                    string[] splitted = currentLine.Split(',');//split the line into fields
                    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (whichLineAmIon == 0)//then we are on the header line
                        {
                            headerLine.Add(splitted[i]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            results.Add(headerLine[i] + " : " + splitted[i]);//add each individual field to the dataSource to create your 1FieldPerLine visual
                        }
                    }
                    whichLineAmIon++;
                }
            }

            lstbx.DataSource = results;//bind your datasource
        }

        private void initializeListBox()
        {
            lstbx.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lstbx.BackColor = Color.Azure;
            this.Controls.Add(lstbx);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here string[] Line = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
    lines.Add(Line);

You're add an array of strings instead a string.

For resolve this, you have to do other for, like this.

```
string[] Line = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < Line.Length ; i++)
{
    lines.Add(Line[i]);
    Row++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your List box shows only object.Bind it to DisplayMemberPath property.

Comment: ListBox displays in a linear manner. Each entry in the DataSource will spawn 1 line in the ListBox. Since he is currently adding the whole line as 1 entry in the data source, then each ListBox line would represent 1 _whole_ CSV line. This is not what he wants. According to the screenshots, he wants to break down each line into individual fields, so that each field can be displayed on their own line.